# Form tag attributes in Symfony2 / Twig

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

When I want to add some attributes to symfony2 form elements I can just use the "attr" attribute. But how can I give some id / class / style / other to the starting form tag itself?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
{{ form_widget(form.name, { 'attr': {'class': 'foo'} }) }}
```

This is the correct syntax for a form widget with the class `foo`. In other words a form field in your form.

You can apply the same for the `<form>` tag.

This is done by rendering

```
{{ form_start(form, { 'attr': {'class': 'foo', 'id': 'bar', ... } }) }}
```

See this short documentation on `form_start` [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-start-view-variables)

> Renders the start tag of a form. This helper takes care of printing the configured method and target action of the form. It will also include the correct enctype property if the form contains upload fields.

You might also be interested in form variables. They are documented [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#more-about-form-variables). All in all there is a whole documentation on all functions and variables you can use [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html)

I wouldn't recommend you to use inline styles. Just do the styling with the ID and/or class you gave the form.

Comment: Sorry I just forgot to clear the cache that's why it didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Worth adding that in order to set the ```action``` you don't need to put it inside of ```attr``` it can be on the highest level of options array.